# how to set the special roles to an account in orionjs?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I want to linked certain roles with certain accounts via orion.js(a cms system development by meteor.js) via javascript code.

How to do it? Can you tell me where is the role table and which object is role managment objet? where I can get the role list?

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it, for example in fixture files:

```
  Accounts.createUser({
    username: 'admin',
    email: 'someone@somedomain.com',
    password: '123456',
    profile: { name: 'MyUser1' },
    roles: ['admin'], // or [] if this is not an admin
  });
```